# How can I search for files on a Samba share in Linux?

Tags: linux, fedora, network-shares, samba, nautilus

I recently installed Fedora 23 on an old PC for a friend who wanted a basic office machine. Everything works fine, but the feature they really need is file search in a Windows (Samba) shared directory.

I've successfully mounted the shared directory in Nautilus (Gnome Files) but searching doesn't work in that directory: it always returns zero results. Is this a bug in Nautilus or do I need to enable some indexing feature in order to get search working?

The end-user is not familiar with the Linux command-line, so any solution must be GUI-based, ideally within Nautilus. If another GUI is used, it should run on Fedora 23 (in Gnome).

Comment: FYI I worked around this issue by using [BitTorrent Sync](https://www.getsync.com/). This works because the synced folder is a local folder like any other, so it isn't restricted to non-recursive searching like a network folder is. I'm leaving this as a comment rather than an answer because it's a work-around and not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a search starting from `/run/user/$UID/gvfs`.

**Edit**

You can have that share under her/his "Risorse" section:

[image]

I believe PCManFM is less sophisticated than Nautilus.

Comment: Sorry, that isn't a good solution for me. Personally, I would take that approach, but the user here isn't so computer-literate and wouldn't want to use the terminal. I don't mind if the solution involves some app other than Nautilus, but ideally I'd just like to get Nautilus's search working.

Comment: Can't you open that position from Nautilus? Replace `$UID` variable with that particular user ID; maybe you can bookmark it on the file manager for recurrent use

Comment: @AllanLewis - You should indicate that in your question.

Comment: @Ramhound I've edited my question.